# How to keep Artifacts from old builds on AWS Amplify Hosting?

Tags: frontend, aws-amplify

Users who stay on old site after a new build will fail in fetching outdated js files from the last build, then the whole web app crashed.
If amplify could keep old files after a new build, this won't be a problem.
but i can't find how to do this in amplify.

I tried to set vite config `build.emptyOutDir` to false to let vite don't delete output files.
but it's not work.
it's seem that amplify deploy web app by docker, a new deploy cames with a fresh new docker image, so no old files from last build could be kept.